# wordpress/woocomerce get variation_description withouth html escaping

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I have some products with variations and want to provide some data in the description as JSON for working with it in the template.

In the product, I can see the data is correct, for example:

```
{"next_date":"2021-05-12","days":"-1217","tmp1":"1","tmp2":"149.53400000000002","tmp3"
```

The Data is also saved clear in the db in the meta field _variation_description

I loop now all variations (All JSON are only samples)

```
foreach ( $product->get_available_variations() as $variation_data ) {
            print_r( $variation_data['variation_description']);
```

And I get

```
 <p>{&#8222;next_date&#8220;:&#8220;2019-03-11&#8243;,&#8220;days&#8220;:&#8220;-2009&#8243;,&#8220;tmp1&#8243;:&#8220;1&#8243;,&#8220
```

I can now use strip_tags and use HTML entity decode, but then I have the problem

```
{„next_date“....
```

In the $variation_data I have the variation ID, so I can get the data over get_meta, but this seems is not the best thing I should use because it's another sql query I don't need.

So is here any way to get the old unescaped JSON in this field?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably try this:

change the default **array** output to **object** output:

```
foreach ( $product->get_available_variations('objects') as $variation ) {
            print_r( $variation->get_description());
}
```

This will give you an object of variations and then from that object you can get the description using the **get_description()** method which will not execute another query as you mentioned.

Comment: nice thanks this does exactly what i want, I've tried something like this already and got the error that's is not possible on arrays but you do a "object" requests and on this it's working. I will mark your answer in 4 min as correct solution when the system here let me do.

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. Do accept the answer so that other people looking for a similar solution can trust this answer :)